# No login screen after upgrade to 17.10 (edited)

Tags: login, 17.10

[image]I have upgraded my system to Ubuntu 17.10. After reboot I am unable to get login screen. I am able to login to my computer by Ctrl+Alt+F2. Screen shot is attached for further information regarding errors and processes.

I am able to login to my computer by recovery mode also. Where only gnome works. Unity and Ubuntu on Xorg gives only login loops.

What I already did...

1. Purged Xserver and reinstalled it.
2. Upgraded kernel by synaptic. (Through recovery mode login)

[image]

Updation
1. All the process initialization works fine at the time of boot.
2. Still not getting gdm login screen. (Version gdm3)

Comment: Earlier before update I was getting GUI on Alt+Ctrl+F6. Now when I press Alt+Ctrl+F1 I get different GUI (I think may be for 17.10 desktop). And by Alt+Ctrl+F2 I get normal GUI, as I worked with in 16.04 LTS.

Comment: You might want to consider adding a bounty to this question if it's still an issue for you. Are you able to login through the TUI?

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the display manager, or switching. You can reinstall GDM3 by logging in to a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, and running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3
```

or, try `lightdm`, which is what was used in older versions of Ubuntu, you can install that by:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

it should then ask you which display manager you want to be the default, choose lightdm, and then run

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

to avoid a reboot.

Another thing worth trying is removing the `.Xauthority` file with:

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
```

from the terminal, and your display manager should re-create the file, and hopefully start working again.

Comment: I tried this, but problem is not solved.

Comment: Didn't help me either. :/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, Upgrading the kernel has almost nothing to do with display managers you have performed dist-upgrade. 
I would rather suggest you do the following by entering to CLI mode using `ctrl+alt+F1` and update and upgrade the system using.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can now check your login screen. If it still doesnot appear, now try reinstalling gdm3. and yes don't forget to reboot after the installation.

The final but not recommended but you can use to backup your system file is using the following command after you enter CLI mode:

```
startx
```